# Why does text ellipsis not work in flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I found that the text ellipsis set in `.inner_right` does not work. After testing, I added `overflow: hidden` to the `.left` box, and the ellipsis appeared. how to explain this situation?

```css
.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  background-color: blue;
  /* overflow: hidden;  It will not work without adding this */
}

.right {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: black;
}

.left .inner_left {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

.left .inner_right {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="inner_left"></div>
    <div class="inner_right">
      some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by `does not work`? To me, it seems that it is working perfectly.

Comment: _and the ellipsis appeared_ <- This doesn't seems to be a problem. It's just like it is working as expected because its overflow `ellipsis`.

Comment: I didn't add `overflow: hidden` on `.left` box   it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also fix your problem by adding a width value on your `.left` element